# app crashes when releasing object

Tags: iphone

I am working on an iPhone application.In that app I am switching from one view to another by

```
loginpage *loginview = [[loginpage alloc]init];

[self presentModelViewController:loginview animated:YES];
```

`[loginview release];`

this code.It is working fine.But in the second view(loginpage) when I press back button than this code

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:Yes];
```

gets fired and after that app crashes.Can anyone please help me out.Please suggest me what should I do to resolve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the loginView is released automatically after you call 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' so you shouldn't release the loginView.

Comment: `gets fired and after that app crashes` then the crash happens because of the code executed after the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` method

Comment: @ZeusAlexander that's not true... loginview has retain count 1 before presenting, after presenting the retain count is 2, then it needs to be released and the retain count goes back to 1 and after dismiss it gets to zero and the object is freed

Comment: hay.. in this code there is no problem... debug and then you will find  another problem in your app. some another value is releasing in that's Y your app crash.

Comment: What exactly gets logged when it crashes?

Comment: @graver yeah you're right, I tested it myself. The problem must be somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Try commenting [loginview release];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare the Object in `.h` file. that 
    loginpage *loginview; and release the Object in
`-(void)dealloc` method.

Comment: I have done similar to what you have suggested.But I have declared variable in .m file instead of .h file.Is that ok?

Comment: If you declared the variable in .m file it shows a memory leak while analysing the application. So just declare in .h file If the answer is use full please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any fault in your code. This code worked fine, just try to find other problem which cause crash. And put crash report over it.

Answer (score 0):

some problem may be in your dealloc method of loginView class.. add break point to this method, and run step by step... also enable zombie.